# ¿Como deshabilitar un select cuando el valor ya ha sido seleccionado anteriormente?

Tags: javascript, laravel, select2

Espero puedan ayudarme con lo que necesito, pues estoy intentando crear un punto de ventas en Laravel, para ello también necesito usar series de producto.

La mecánica es la siguiente, en el panel están los productos, selecciono uno, luego dentro del cuadro de detalles de precio y cantidad aparece una lista desplegable donde tengo que seleccionar la serie.

Lo que necesito es que cuando seleccione esta serie, si agrego nuevamente el producto, obviamente tendrá los mismos números de serie en el select para escoger, el que ya había seleccionado se encuentre deshabilitado u oculto.

Este es por ejemplo del código donde están las series

```
<select class="form-control lot_number input-sm valid" name="products[2][lot_no_line_id]" aria-invalid="false">
            <option value="">serie</option>
                                                    <option value="1953" data-qty_available="1.0000" data-msg-max="Solamente 1.00 :unidad disponible en el numero de serie seleccionado">180919'5716579    </option>
                                                    <option value="1955" data-qty_available="1.0000" data-msg-max="Solamente 1.00 :unidad disponible en el numero de serie seleccionado">180919'5716588    </option>
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el atributo `hidden` a la poción a ocultar.

Ejemplo:

En este ejemplo, al seleccionar un valor del desplegable, es se oculta de la lista de opciones.. Para ello se usa el evento `change` y una función anónima.

```js
document.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  document.querySelector('option[value="' + e.target.value +'"]').hidden = true;
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Seleccione una opción</option>
  <option value="0">Primero</option>
  <option value="1">Segundo</option>
  <option value="2">Tercero</option>
</select>
```

Nótese que el valor seleccionado se mostrará como el valor del desplegable pero no en la lista de opciones.

Comment: Si, el problema es que tengo varios selects, es decir cuando agrego un producto se genera otro select con los mismos valores.

Lo que quisiera es que una vez seleccionada este valor no se pueda volver a seleccionar en la presente sesión.

Comment: @Lembes Edita tu pregunta para agregar los detalles relevantes, como este que indicas que tienes varios selects. Aprovecho para sugerir que el código que pegues lo ordenes (espacios/indentación) para que se pueda leer fácilmente. También ayudaría que quitaras todo lo que no sea relevante. Mas detalles en [mcve].